The trait bound xx not satisfied - trait impl with same name found
I have implemented the object_store trait for an object store HDFLS (not hdfs ;))
It is in a crate hdlfs with the structure

lib.rs - containing "pub mod saphdlfs;"

saphdlfs/mod.rs with the object_store::ObjectStore implementation


use object_store::ObjectStore;

pub struct HDLStore {
    pub client: HDLClient,
}

#[async_trait]
impl ObjectStore for HDLStore {

    async fn put(&self, location: &Path, payload:PutPayload) -> Result<PutResult, Error> {
        self.put_opts(location, payload, PutOptions::default()).await
    }
    ...

When I am using the object_store implementation in a rust programm:
use datafusion::error::Result;
use datafusion::prelude::SessionContext;
use hdlfs::saphdlfs::HDLStore;
use object_store::ObjectStore;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {

    ...
   
    let ctx: SessionContext = SessionContext::new();
    let hdl_store = HDLStore::new(&endpoint, cert, key, true, true).unwrap();

    ctx.runtime_env().register_object_store(&endpoint, Arc::new(hdl_store));


The compiler runs into this error:
error[E0277]: the trait bound `HDLStore: object_store::ObjectStore` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:33:56
   |
33 |     ctx.runtime_env().register_object_store(&endpoint, Arc::new(hdl_store));
   |                                                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `object_store::ObjectStore` is not implemented for `HDLStore`
   |
help: trait impl with same name found
  --> /Users/D051079/GitHub/rust/hdlfs-rs/src/saphdlfs/mod.rs:72:1
   |
72 | impl ObjectStore for HDLStore {
   | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: perhaps two different versions of crate `object_store` are being used?


What have I missed and what do I need to do?
Many thanks

This usually means you have two versions of the same dependency (you've implemented using one version but the function is expecting another). Please show your dependencies and their versions.

In both cargo.toml's I have the dependency object_store = "0.10.0". But there is also a dependency in datafusion = "37.1.0" that has the dependency object_store = "0.9.1". There a significant differences that needs some code changes to do. Let's see if this is reason. Thanks.
